# Sync AWS Commercial S3 bucket to AWS GovCloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to sync file from a S3 bucket that resides in a Commercial/Open market region (such as us-east-1) into a S3 bucket on GovCloud.  I can get sync to work if I'm trying to sync between none GovCloud regions us-east-1 to us-west-1.  Does anyone know how to perform this kind of sync with GovCloud?  Also, this sync needs to occur unattended and on a scheduled basis so a manual UI/tool will not suffice.  It must be something that can be scripted such as from an SDK or CLI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Migrating S3 Buckets from AWS to GovCloud - Coveros](https://www.coveros.com/migrating-s3-buckets-from-aws-to-govcloud/) suggests that you need to download from one, then upload to the other rather than copying directly between. [Gov-Cloud-Import Tool: How to Transfer Information Between Identity Boundaries | AWS Government, Education, & Nonprofits Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/publicsector/gov-cloud-import-tool-how-to-transfer-information-between-identity-boundaries/) talks about a tool that might be able to automate this.

Comment: Download+Upload would definitely be required, since AWS GovCloud -- just like AWS China -- is completely isolated from the "main" AWS partition that contains all the other regions.